# How to play audio with OutputAudioQueue in silent mode?

Tags: ios, audio, xamarin.ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Play a sound using AVAudioPlayer when in Silent Mode in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322040/how-to-play-a-sound-using-avaudioplayer-when-in-silent-mode-in-iphone)

Yes, I know, that user asked silence, but it's really necessary in this application and it's predictable for user.

So, is it possible to play sound in silent mode?

Sound is encoded so it's decoding and filling buffer of queue with audio data (if needed - could copy code here). Usually, as I figured out, `AVAudioSession` is using, but is it possible to use it to play not 'full'-file, but file in pieces (packages).

Comment: Jason, thank you! I was confused, that Audio Queue service and Audio Player is near the same. Thanks again : adding this code fix the problem: 'AVAudioSession audioSession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
NSError error;  audioSession.SetCategory(AVAudioSession.CategoryPlayback,out   error);
audioSession.SetActive(true,out error);   UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginReceivingRemoteControlEvents();'

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov you can answer your own question in stackoverflow.com - it's better that way, since people looking for a similar question will see there's an answer available :-)