# Play system sound when iPhone in vibrate mode .

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I am using below code for play system sound in iOS, It is working perfect when iPhone is not in silent mode. But when i put iPhone in silent mode system sound is not play

```
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
NSError *_error  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &_error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(systemSoundID);
```

Please help me out

Comment: seems like you answered your own question!

Comment: Sorry sir, I am not getting you

Comment: Why would you expect a system sound to play while the phone is muted?

Comment: I have certain functionality required same.

Comment: Then use an API that can play sound while the device is muted.  You'll need to switch the audio category.

Comment: I guess - this is restricted by iOS , it will restrict all the tones in silent mode.

Comment: @Mrunal : I have checked in one app. It will work perfect. So this is not restricted by iOS

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740528/play-sound-on-iphone-even-in-silent-mode   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322040/how-to-play-a-sound-using-avaudioplayer-when-in-silent-mode-in-iphone

Comment: @Mrunal : thanks bro, but i have tried this solution also. It is not working for me. i am debugging in iOS 10.0.2